# The SelectedValue property of a ListBox returns wrong value when is binding to the result of a Linq to Entity query

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I want to fill a List Box using a Linq To Entities query. The problem is that the SelectedValue property returns wrong value!

This is the process:

1.Fill the List Box:

```
Dim FirstLevelList = (From FL In db.FirstLevels
                  Where FL.Department.Id = UserDepartment.Id
                  Select New With {
                     .Value = FL,
                     .Display = FL.Title
                  }).ToList
LstFirstLevel.DataSource = FirstLevelList
LstFirstLevel.DisplayMember = "Display"
LstFirstLevel.ValueMember = "Value"
```

2.Convert the SelectedValue to FirstLevel object:

```
Dim SelectedFirstLevel = CType(LstFirstLevel.SelectedValue, FirstLevel)
```

But there is a conversion error at runtime:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousType_0`2[Coding_Generator.FirstLevel,System.String]' to type 'Coding_Generator.FirstLevel'.'

And this is the contents of LstFirstLevel.SelectedValue:
[image]

**But it should be just the .Value index not the whole {.Display, .Value} object!**

Answer (score 0):

Based from the exception message, the `LstFirstLevel.DataSource` property has anonymous type indicated by `Select New With` without mentioning any class name to project into the list.

Try create a placeholder class which contains `Value` and `Display` properties with respective types:

```
Public Class Placeholder

    Public Property Value As FirstLevel
    Public Property Display As String

End Class
```

Then you should use `Select` by mentioning class name to enable casting:

```
Dim FirstLevelList = (From FL In db.FirstLevels
                      Where FL.Department.Id = UserDepartment.Id
                      Select New Placeholder With {
                         .Value = FL,
                         .Display = FL.Title
                     }).ToList

LstFirstLevel.DataSource = FirstLevelList
```

And change the cast like this:

```
Dim SelectedListValue = CType(LstFirstLevel.SelectedValue, Placeholder)

Dim SelectedFirstLevel = CType(SelectedListValue.Value, FirstLevel)
```

Reference: [Return a LINQ Query Result as a Specific Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/how-to-return-a-linq-query-result-as-a-specific-type)

Comment: I do not need to cast the resault to FirstLevel. FL function is of type FirstLevel

Comment: I know that FL is already has type of FirstLevel, but `Select New With` actually returns list of anonymous types, which is the cause of `InvalidCastException` when using `CType`. Either `Select New FirstLevel With` or maybe `Select FL` (if you want to include all properties of FL) should work.